# Google app script doesn't populate spreadsheet values on a particular cell only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following PO Generator App. I am using Google spreadsheet default purchase order template to populate values from another sheet using google app script (some JavaScript codes). When I click the add item custom made button on sheet named POS, Service and unit prices are populated, but quantity is not populated. As a result, I cannot calculate the total values. I am new to JavaScript can anyone help me figure out why the quantity is not displayed. The codes are as follows:

```js
function AddItem()
{
  
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MENU SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("POS");
  var itemSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ITEMS");
  
  //GET NEXT ROW OF PO SHEET
  var lastrowPO = poSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  //GET LAST ROW OF ITEM SHEET
  var lastrowItem = itemSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // GET VALUE OF PART AND QUANTITY
  var part = poSheet.getRange('B13').getValue();
  var quantity = poSheet.getRange('B14').getValue();
  
  // GET UNIT PRICE FROM ITEM SHEET
  for(var i = 2; i <= lastrowItem; i++)
  {
    if(part == itemSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
    {
      var description = itemSheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var unitCost = itemSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    }
  }
  
  // POPULATE PO SHEET
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 1).setValue(part);
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 2).setValue(description);
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 3).setValue(quantity);
  poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 4).setValue(unitCost).setNumberFormat("$#,###.00");
  
}


function createPO()
{
  //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE MENU SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("POS");
  var vendorSheet = ss.getSheetByName("VENDORS");
  var settingSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SETTINGS");
  var printSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PRINT PO");
  
  //GET VALUES
  var name = poSheet.getRange(6,2).getValue();
  var source = poSheet.getRange(9,2).getValue();
  var approval_date = poSheet.getRange(8,2).getValue();
  var target = poSheet.getRange(10,2).getValue();
  var terms = poSheet.getRange(7,2).getValue();
  var witholding = poSheet.getRange(11,2).getValue();
  var po_number = settingSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
  var next_po_number = po_number + 1;
  settingSheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(next_po_number);
  
  // GET VENDOR LAST ROW
  var lastrowVendor = vendorSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // GET CUSTOMER FIELDS
  for(var i = 2; i <= lastrowVendor; i++)
  {
    if(name == vendorSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
    {
      var bank = vendorSheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var bank_account = vendorSheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var address = vendorSheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
      var city = vendorSheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
      var region = vendorSheet.getRange(i,6).getValue();
      var phone_number = vendorSheet.getRange(i,7).getValue();
      var email = vendorSheet.getRange(i,8).getValue();
      var tax_rate = vendorSheet.getRange(i,9).getValue();
    }
  }
  
  // SET PO DATE
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()+1;
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var date = currentMonth.toString() + '/' + currentDate.getDate().toString() + '/' + currentYear.toString();

  // GET LAST ROW OF PRINT SHEET
  var lastrowPrint = printSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // FIND HOW MANY ITEMS ROWS TO DELETE
  var x_count = 0
  for(var v = 27; v <= lastrowPrint; v++)
  {
    
    if(printSheet.getRange(v, 6).getValue() != 'Subtotal')
    {  
      x_count++;
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  
  var lastrowPrint = 27 + x_count;
  
  //Logger.log(lastrowPrint);
  
  // DELETE ITEMS ROWS FROM PO
  if((lastrowPrint - 27) != 0)
  {
    printSheet.deleteRows(27, lastrowPrint - 27);
  }  
  
  // SET VALUES ON PO  
  printSheet.getRange('B18').setValue(name).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontWeight("bold").setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('B19').setValue(bank).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('B20').setValue(bank_account).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('B21').setValue(address +', ' + city + ' ' + region).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('B22').setValue(phone_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('B23').setValue(email).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  
  printSheet.getRange('B11').setValue(date).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('D11').setValue(source).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('F11').setValue(po_number).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('B14').setValue(approval_date).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('D14').setValue(target).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("3e01b84");
  printSheet.getRange('F14').setValue(terms).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("3e01b84");
  
  printSheet.getRange('H28').setValue(witholding).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#E01B84");
  printSheet.getRange('H29').setValue(tax_rate).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
  
  
  // GET LAST ROW OF PO SHEET
  var lastrowPO = poSheet.getLastRow();

  var z = 0;
  var subTotal = 0;
  for(var y = 17; y <= lastrowPO; y++)
  {
    //INSERT ROW ON PRINT SHEET
    printSheet.insertRowsAfter(26 + z, 1);
    
    //GET ITEM VALUES FROM PO SHEET
    var part = poSheet.getRange(y, 1).getValue();
    var description = poSheet.getRange(y, 2).getValue();
    var quantity = poSheet.getRange(y, 3).getValue();
    var unitPrice = poSheet.getRange(y, 4).getValue();
    
    // PRICE TOTALS
    var totalPrice = quantity * unitPrice;
    subTotal = subTotal + totalPrice;
    
    // POPULATE TOTALS ON PRINT SHEET
    printSheet.getRange(26 + z + 1, 2).setValue(part).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("black");
    printSheet.getRange(26 + z + 1, 3).setValue(description).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
    printSheet.getRange(26 + z + 1, 6).setValue(quantity).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
    printSheet.getRange(26 + z + 1, 7).setValue(unitPrice).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
    printSheet.getRange(26 + z + 1, 8).setValue(totalPrice).setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize(10).setFontColor("#e01b84");
    
    z++;
  }
  
  // SET TOTAL
  printSheet.getRange(26 + z + 1, 8)
  .setValue(subTotal)
  .setNumberFormat("$#,###.00")
  .setFontFamily('Roboto')
  .setFontSize(10)
  .setFontColor("black");
  
  var totalPO = subTotal;
  
  // CALL PO LOG
  POLog(po_number, name, date, approval_date, totalPO)

}

function POLog(po_number, name, date, approval_date, totalPO)
{
  
   //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE PO LOG SHEET          
  var POLogSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PO LOG"); 
  
  //GET LAST ROW OF PO LOG SHEET
  var nextRowPO = POLogSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  //POPULATE INVOICE LOG
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 1).setValue(po_number);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 2).setValue(name);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 3).setValue(date);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 4).setValue(approval_date);
  POLogSheet.getRange(nextRowPO, 5).setValue(totalPO);

}

function ClearInvoice()
{
    //DEFINE ALL ACTIVE SHEETS
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  //DEFINE PO SHEET          
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName("POS");
  
  
  //SET VALUES TO NOTHING
  poSheet.getRange(6,2).setValue("");
  poSheet.getRange(7,2).setValue("");
  poSheet.getRange(8,2).setValue("");  
  poSheet.getRange(9,2).setValue("");  
  poSheet.getRange(10,2).setValue("");
  poSheet.getRange(11,2).setValue("");  
  poSheet.getRange(13,2).setValue("");  
  poSheet.getRange(14,2).setValue("");
  
  //CLEAR ITEMS
  poSheet.getRange("A17:D1000").clear();

}
```

Comment: I would guess that the quantity is not found in B14 because in createPO the quantity appears to be in column C.  So you should use the debugger to determine where you went wrong.

Comment: Hi Ruben thank you for your response. As per your instruction, I used the debugger on var quantity line and It says it is undefined. Then I debugged AddItem function's line: poSheet.getRange(lastrowPO, 3).setValue(quantity); It shows the inputted  quantity in debug section but it fails to actually populate the quantity on the lastrowPO, 3 column  cell of the spreadsheet.  3 is the column number where the inputted quantity should be displayed and the calculation is made for the CreatePO(section).

Comment: Keep working backwards until you figure out what's missing.  It's like a plumbing problem there's no water coming out of the sprinkler where do look for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I finally get the bug. The problem is as follows:

1. The last entry was the quantity amount. After inputting quantity amount I supposed to hit the enter key. However, I was directly clicking the custom made AddItem button. As a result, the quantity amount was only missing from the last outputs.
2. The solution is hitting the enter key after inputting the quantity amount and then clicking the AddItem button on the spreadsheet.

Therefore, the appscript code provided works fine.